# Type annotations for variables without initial value

Tags: python, type-annotation

I've been reading through PEP484 and 526 and still can't figure out what is a better way to do type annotations for variables without an initial value.

Say, you have a class and in the `__init__` you want to declare a variable, but without providing an initial value where assignment happens later in the code. Usually what I would normally do is:

```py
from typing import Optional, List

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_value: Optional[int] = None
        self.other_var: Optional[List] = None

    def _some_method(self) -> None:
        self.some_value = 42
```

This works, but I feel like using Optional makes `__init__` overly busy and harder to read. Instead what I could do is:

```py
from typing import List

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_value: int
        self.other_var: List

    def _some_method(self) -> None:
        self.some_value = 42
```

Obviously, this leaves variables uninitialized, but as long as they are correctly assigned to before being referenced, everything works just fine and makes it easier to read if I have a lot of class attributes declared in `__init__`.

Are there any specific issues that could arise from leaving variables uninitialized when using the second approach?

Comment: Type annotations don't affect the behavior of the script, they're just to inform the programmer of the intent. How could there be any issues?

Comment: `self.some_value: int = None` is ok. It's like declaration without initialization in typed languages.

Comment: Forget the annotations for now. What *behavior* do you want? Do you want the attributes initialized to None? Do you want the attributes to be unset? Pick the *behavior* you want, then use whatever annotations are correct for the code that gives that behavior.

Comment: @Barmar, I should probably clarify that I'm specifically wondering if any specific issues can arise from leaving variables uninitialized (int the second approach)? Not from type annotations *per se*.'

Comment: It depends on what the function does with the variables. But it's quite common to leave variables uninitialized until you need to store into them.

Comment: @Poolka: It's "okay" in the sense that it runs without throwing anything, but it's semantically incorrect, and type checkers will report an error.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any specific issues that could arise from leaving variables uninitialized when using the second approach?

Yes. Adding type annotations without setting a value is for the type checker only. You won't actually create the variable. Just have a look at the error thrown from your second example:

```py
from typing import List


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_value: int
        self.other_var: List

    def _some_method(self) -> None:
        self.some_value = 42


sc = SomeClass()
print(sc.some_value)
```

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(sc.some_value)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'SomeClass' object has no attribute 'some_value'
```

Note that the error is "has no attribute". In other words, the attribute was not created at all.

As of Python 3.10 the syntax has gotten a little cleaner, so you don't need the import from `typing` anymore, and you don't need `Optional` anymore. This is how I'd type your class:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_value: int | None = None
        self.other_var: list[int] | None = None

    def _some_method(self) -> None:
        self.some_value = 42
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like how crowded the `__init__` method gets, you could split between private and public attributes and annotate only the latter.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._some_value = None
    
    @property
    def some_value(self) -> Optional[int]:  # int | None in Python >= 3.10
        return self._some_value
    
    @some_value.setter
    def some_value(self, value):
        self._some_value = value

    def _some_method(self) -> None:
        self.some_value = 42
```